# Avoid asking: I'm trying to do X as seen on site Y. How do I do it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, help-center

On Stackoverflow, I often come across questions of the type:

I'm trying to do X as seen on site Y.
How do I do it?

Could this type of reverse engineering question be added to [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

It seems that they come up often enough and get voted-down/closed enough to warrant a warning in the help center.

For example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/17036209/1947286
- [Transitions between pages with refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085594/transitions-between-pages-with-refresh)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914729/how-to-make-image-map-popup-with-jquery

Related: [How to handle "How do they do that" type of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142857/how-to-handle-how-do-they-do-that-type-of-questions)

Comment: Do you have some examples?

Comment: @FDinoff This one hasn't been down-voted or closed yet, but its an example of the sort of question I'm talking about http://stackoverflow.com/q/17076986/1947286

Comment: There is a close reason being refined that deals with this, basically saying that questions that just point to third party code without including any specific bits and end in 'how do I do what they did?' aren't on topic. It's not yet baked, so I'm not yet _officially_ answering - but this is one of the cases we considered when coming up with the initial set of close reasons for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FDinoff See update.

Comment: @TimPost, any movement?